# Frequent internet disconnection in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, internet, 15.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 in my laptop(DELL Latitude E5540). I am facig frequent internet disconnection, both in LAN and WiFi. None of the others in my network is facing any such issue.

Result of `lspci -v | grep -iA 7 network` is

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Sometimes it works for a few hours without facing the issue. But sometimes it keeps getting disconnected too often. After a few seconds(20-25sec), connection comes back. Because of this, I am facing issues while downloading as all the downloads getting interrupted in between.

Anyone else is facing this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried almost all the possible answers saw in different sites, but none of them solved my issue. Finally, I went back to 14.04 and then network issue was resolved. However, with 14.04, I had issues with Docking Station usage. For that, I upgraded the kernel to 3.18 by following [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-linux-kernel-3-18-ubuntu/) link.